# Show whether f is integrable or not

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

Suppose $f : [a, b] → R$ is bounded and satisfies $f ≥ 0$ and

$$\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f=0$$

Can we conclude it is integrable? Prove it either way

Without considering the non-negativity of $f$, I was able to do the following:

Let $f(x)=0$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ & $f(x)=-1$ when $x \in \mathbb{Q^c}$

Constructing a partition $p$, suppose $p=\{ 0=x_0<x_1<x_2<...<x_n=1 \}$

Then $U(p,f)= \sum_{r=1}^n M_r\delta _r =0$; $infU(p,f)=0$ i.e $\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f=0$

But $f$ is not riemann integrable as $L(p,f)=\sum_{r=1}^n m_r \delta_r =-1, \ supL(p,f)=-1.$

Since $\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f \neq {\int_{\underline{0}}^{1}}f$, $f$ is not riemann integrable.

Is there a way I could modify my solution (substitute different values of $f$) or approach this differently to make it valid for $f\ge 0$?

Comment: Is $[0,1]\subset[a,b]$? What is $\bar{1}$?

Comment: The overbar should be on the $\int$ sign, not the $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is non-negative, then, for each partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, $L(f,P)\geqslant0$. Therefore, $\underline{\int_a^b}f=0$. Since we are assuming that $\overline{\int_a^b}f=0$, $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a function? Since here I have supposed $f$ to be either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: If $L(f,p)\ge 0$ then $\int_{\underbar{a}}^bf\ge 0$ not zero.

Comment: Where did you say that $f$ only takes the vakues $\pm1$? What you wrote was that $f\geqslant0$.

Comment: The question says $ f\ge 0$ but I supposed $f$ to be $-1$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: If $f\geqslant0$ and $f$ only takes the values $\pm1$, then $f$ is constant and only takes the value $1$. Not very interesting, right?!